# How to extract the uppercase as well as some substring from pandas dataframe using extract?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

This question is the follow up question to previous question [How to extract only uppercase substring from pandas series?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64452218/how-to-extract-only-uppercase-substring-from-pandas-series?noredirect=1#64452218).

Instead of changing the old question, I decided to ask the new question.

My aim is to extract the aggregation method `agg` and feature name `feat` from a column named item.

Here is the question:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['num','bool', 'cat', 'cat.COUNT(example)','cat.N_MOST_COMMON(example.ord)[2]','cat.FIRST(example.ord)','cat.FIRST(example.num)']})


regexp = (r'(?P<agg>) '     # agg is the word in uppercase (all other substring is lowercased)
         r'(?P<feat>), '   # 1. if there is no uppercase, whole string is feat
                           # 2. if there is uppercase the substring after example. is feat
                           # e.g. cat ==> cat
                           # cat.N_MOST_COMMON(example.ord)[2] ==> ord
                  
        )

df[['agg','feat']] = df.col.str.extract(regexp,expand=True)

# I am not sure how to build up regexp here.


print(df)

"""
Required output


                                item   agg               feat
0                                num                     num
1                               bool                     bool
2                                cat                     cat
3                 cat.COUNT(example)   COUNT                           # note: here feat is empty
4  cat.N_MOST_COMMON(example.ord)[2]   N_MOST_COMMON     ord
5             cat.FIRST(example.ord)   FIRST             ord
6             cat.FIRST(example.num)   FIRST             num
""";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `feat`, since you already got the answer to `agg` in your other StackOverflow question, I think you can use the following to extract two different series based off two different patterns that are separated with `|` and then `fillna()` one series with another.

1. `^([^A-Z]*$)` should only return the full string if the full string is lowercase
2. `[^a-z].*example\.([a-z]+)\).*$` should only return strings after `example.` and before `)` only if there is uppercase in the string prior to `example.`

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['num','bool', 'cat', 'cat.COUNT(example)','cat.N_MOST_COMMON(example.ord)[2]','cat.FIRST(example.ord)','cat.FIRST(example.num)']})

s = df['item'].str.extract('^([^A-Z]*$)|[^a-z].*example\.([a-z]+)\).*$', expand=True)
df['feat'] = s[0].fillna(s[1]).fillna('')
df
Out[1]: 
                                item  feat
0                                num   num
1                               bool  bool
2                                cat   cat
3                 cat.COUNT(example)      
4  cat.N_MOST_COMMON(example.ord)[2]   ord
5             cat.FIRST(example.ord)   ord
6             cat.FIRST(example.num)   num
```

The above gives you the output you are looking for your sample data and holds to your conditions. However:

1. What if there are UPPERCASE after `example.`? Current output would return `''`

see example #2 below with some of the data changed according to above point:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'item': ['num','cat.count(example.AAA)', 'cat.count(example.aaa)', 'cat.count(example)','cat.N_MOST_COMMON(example.ord)[2]','cat.FIRST(example.ord)','cat.FIRST(example.num)']})

s = df['item'].str.extract('^([^A-Z]*$)|[^a-z].*example\.([a-z]+)\).*$', expand=True)
df['feat'] = s[0].fillna(s[1]).fillna('')
df
Out[2]: 
                                item                    feat
0                                num                     num
1             cat.count(example.AAA)                        
2             cat.count(example.aaa)  cat.count(example.aaa)
3                 cat.count(example)      cat.count(example)
4  cat.N_MOST_COMMON(example.ord)[2]                     ord
5             cat.FIRST(example.ord)                     ord
6             cat.FIRST(example.num)                     num
```